# How to modify this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array:

```
input_array = ["aa", "aa", "--", "--", "--", "aa", "--", "--"]
```

How can I replace the "aa" values in the above example with an incrementing number? Like the following outcome:

```
output_array = [1, 2, "--", "--", "--", 3, "--", "--"]
```

I am trying by maintaining a counter and then looping a number of times for the given key:

This works but I was looking if there exist better way to solve this -

```
a = ["-W-", "-C-", "-A-", "-A-", "-W-", "-W-", "-C-", "-A-", "-A-", "-W-", "---", "---", "---", "-A-", "-W-"]
counts = {"-A-"=>0, "-C-"=>0, "-W-"=>0, "---"=>0 }  
a.each { |e| counts[e] += 1 }

counter = 1
counts.each do |key, value| 
    ax = a.each_index.select{ |i| a[i] == key }
    ax.each_with_index do |ss, si|
        a[ss] = counter
        counter += 1
    end
end

p a
```

Comment: Questions that are just a simple list of requirements are to broad for Stack Overflow. You're expected to post the code you've already written and ask questions about where you're stuck.

Comment: I agree with you, modified my question.

Comment: Okay, So what have you tried now? where are you stuck? Have you looked at the ruby array documentation https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing to documentation but it would be great if you can suggest a solution with O(n). My attempts are failing to finish in time.

Comment: @HimanshuMehta I will suggest you to put your code so we can provide improvement in it

Comment: a = ["aa", "aa", "--", "--", "--", "aa", "--", "--"]

counts = Hash.new(0)

a.each { |a| counts[a] += 1 } and maintaining a counter.

Than looping no of times for given key. Sorry not able to edit properly in comment.

Comment: It really sounds like you're trying to cheat at either an interview or a programming contest.

Comment: Nope @meagar. And if you cannot suggest solution it's okay but I will suggest don't judge. I am learning for self improvement.

Comment: Seeing that you've already tried some things yourself, here's some help: https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/3f3ecabc38b17c162174abc3142c5ea7

Comment: Not sure why this has been put on hold, anyway even though the code will look bad in a comment,  here is how I would do it:
array = ["-W-", "-C-", "-A-", "-A-", "-W-", "-W-", "-C-", "-A-", "-A-", "-W-", "---", "---", "---", "-A-", "-W-"]

elements = ["-A-", "-C-", "-W-", "---" ]

counts = {}

elements.each do |el|
  counts[el] = array.count(el)
end

Comment: `n=0; input_array.map { |s| s == 'aa' ? (n=n.next) : s } #=> [1, 2, "--", "--", "--", 3, "--", "--"] `.

Comment: @engineersmnky, good point, but, man, has that been [whooped with an ugly stick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5jHLJce1Go&app=desktop) (2.51 seconds in) or what? `e = 1.step` then `e.next`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `step` is infinitely better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option, counting the occurrence of the sliced array, using [`Array#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) and [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
ary = ["aa", "aa", "--", "--", "--", "aa", "--", "--", "aa"]

ary.map.with_index { |e, i| e == "aa" ? ary[0..i].count("aa") : e }
#=> [1, 2, "--", "--", "--", 3, "--", "--", 4]
```

---

For the second part, if I get the point, you could [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) then [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
a = ["-W-", "-C-", "-A-", "-A-", "-W-", "-W-", "-C-", "-A-", "-A-", "-W-", "---", "---", "---", "-A-", "-W-"]
a.group_by { |e| e }.transform_values { |v| v.size }
#=> {"-W-"=>5, "-C-"=>2, "-A-"=>5, "---"=>3}
```